# Using multiprocessing -Pool- with -sklearn-, code runs but cores dont show any work

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to do some machine learning on about 31 000 rows and 1000 columns. It takes a long time so I thought I could parallelize the job, so I made it into a funciton and try to use the Tool on my Windows 10 with jupyter notebook. But it just works and when I look at my cores on the Task Manager they are not working. Is there something wrong with the code or is it just not supported?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_dev, X_test, y_dev, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from multiprocessing import Pool
from datetime import datetime as dt

def tree_paralel(x):
    tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="gini", max_depth= x, random_state=1)  
    accuracy_ = []
    for train_idx, val_idx in kfolds.split(X_dev, y_dev):

        X_train, y_train, = X_dev.iloc[train_idx], y_dev.iloc[train_idx]
        X_val, y_val = X_dev.iloc[val_idx], y_dev.iloc[val_idx] 

        X_train = pd.DataFrame(im.fit_transform(X_train),index = X_train.index)
        X_val = pd.DataFrame(im.transform(X_val), index = X_val.index)
        tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = tree.predict(X_val)
        accuracy_.append(accuracy_score(y_val, y_pred))
    print("This was the "+str(x)+" iteration", (dt.now() - start).total_seconds())
    return accuracy_
```

And then use the multiprocessing tool:

```
kfolds = KFold(n_splits=10)
accuracy = []
im = Imputer()

p = Pool(5)

input_ = range(1,11)
output_ = []
start = dt.now()
for result in p.imap(tree_paralel, input_):
    output_.append(result)
p.close()
print("Time:", (dt.now() - start).total_seconds())
```

Comment: It is strange, when I tried to use it on my macbook with a small sample, it uses all the cores on the mac, but on the windows nothing happens ...

Comment: Are you using IPython by any chance (or jupyter for that matter)? It's a known issue that `Pool` won't work in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: Yea, as I mentioned I use the Jupyter notebook so you might be correct that its the notebook which is causing the issue :/ I guess I can save it as a .py file and run it from my terminal? I have never done that before so unsure what it means in practice doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue when using interactive python. 
Quoting [the note from *Using a pool of workers*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) section from `multiprocessing` documentation:

> Note: Functionality within this package requires that the __ main__ module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. **This means that some examples, such as the multiprocessing.pool.Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter**.

See also the [multiprocessing Programming Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming).

By the way, I didn't get what you need to accomplish with your code. Doesn't using `GridSearchCV` with `n_jobs=5` solve your issue (and greatly simplifies your code)?

Comment: I am optimizing the hyperparameter of the decision tree using the kfolds to create some training and validation samples, I dont know the GridsearchCV model, but I think you are right that the notebook is causing the issue.